# How to scroll a UIScrollView using animate without interrupting other functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

In this app, you can tap on verses to highlight them. I added scrolling functionality so that it scrolls on its own using animate. But whenever the scroll starts, I can't tap the verses anymore until I stop the scrolling. Here's my code so far:

```swift
@objc func move_view() {
    print("moved view")
    self.current_scroll_position += 3
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.scroll_view.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(self.current_scroll_position))
    }, completion: nil)
}

// start scrolling
print("start scrolling")
self.current_scroll_position = Int(self.scroll_view.contentOffset.y)

self.scroll_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.5), target: self, selector: #selector(self.move_view), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.current.add(self.scroll_timer, forMode: .commonModes)

self.is_scrolling = true
```

Here's the highlighting without the scroll:

[image: without scroll]

And this is what it looks like with scroll:

[image: with scroll]

As you can see, I can't tap when it's scrolling, how can I fix this?

Comment: AFAIK, this an iOS premise. iOS gives all its capacity to user experience, thus scrolling smoothly is part of this premise and all resources is allocate for this task. You can see this behaviour also on Chrome and Safari, while scrolling, the page stops loading.... at least is what I have so far by my research, there is no work around

Comment: `UIViewAnimationOptions` includes `allowUserInteraction`, it's possible that could help. e.g.,  `options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: @Samantha, that worked! If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewAnimationOptions` has a constant `allowUserInteraction`, so you can use it like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    self.scroll_view.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(self.current_scroll_position))
}, completion: nil)
```

Which should allow user gestures on the view while animations are taking place.